# Making lists with nested spans response correctly in CSS

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCH8Y.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaUfh.jpg

the part inside the red square is making problems. 
The css classes used here look like this:

```
.overflowHidden{
  overflow: hidden;
 }
.floatLeft{
  float: left;
}

.floatRight{
 float: right;
}

.floatAuto{
 float: auto;
}
.alignLeft {
 text-align: left;
}

.alignRight {
 text-align: right;
}

.alignCenter {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}

.alignJustify{
  text-align: justify;
}

.summaryListStyle{
    /*padding-left: 25%;*/
    list-style-position: outside;
 }
```

the markup looks like this

```
              <h6 class = "alignLeft">Preisberechnung:</h6>

          <ul class = "alignJustify">
            <li class="summaryListStyle">
              <span class="floatAuto alignLeft">{{ car.basemodel.name }}:</span>
              <span class="floatRight">{{ car.basemodel.price }} €</span>
            </li>

            <li class="summaryListStyle">
              <span class="floatAuto alignLeft">{{ car.edition.name }}:</span>
              <span class="floatRight">{{ car.edition.price }} €</span>
            </li>

            <li class="summaryListStyle" *ngFor="let extra of car.edition.extras">
              <span class="floatAuto alignLeft">{{ extra.name }} (gehört zur Edition):</span>
              <span class="floatRight">{{ extra.price }} €</span>
            </li>

            <li class="summaryListStyle" *ngFor="let extra of car.extras">
              <span class="floatAuto alignLeft">{{ extra.name }}:</span>
              <span class="floatRight">{{ extra.price }} €</span>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div *ngIf="discount != 0.00">
            Die Preise für Sonderausstattungen sind um {{ discount }}% reduziert.
          </div>
          <div class="summaryTotalPriceStyle exposedVerticallyTop">
            Gesamtpreis: {{ price }}    €
          </div>
```

I tried multiple mixtures of the above shown css classes on the HTML elements, some worked better, some worse, but there was none which did the job perfectly. At some zoomlevel, the thing always crashed. I think this problem is connected to the use of the float property, but unfortunately I didnt find any other way to make the SPAN elements inside the LI elements move to the right. text-align property didn't have any effect, it didnt move the respective any further to the right.

Comment: you need to put a max-width to the alignLeft element. In this way you can have enough space for the price span

Comment: @aflyzer Tried it out, but actually applying the max-width property made things worse, no matter which values (1 to 100px, 1% to 100%) I used.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot? It would be really easier with snipped code..

Comment: @aflyzer I uploaded images, see the links at the top of my OP?
Or do you need more/different screenshots? If so, which?

Comment: `clear:both` on the LI can at least make the content of the “next” item move down accordingly. If you want more than that, you might need a different structure (or formatting.)

Comment: @04FS Thanks, its not perfect yet, but it works a lot better than before! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my snippet code and let me know

```css
.panel{
  width: 270px;
  background:grey;
  padding:15px;
}
ul{
  padding-left:50px;
}
ul li{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul li .content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
ul li > .content span:first-of-type{
  max-width:80%;
}
ul li > .content span:last-of-type{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="content">
        <span>Text 132456:</span>
        <span> 26 €</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="content">
        <span>Lorem ipsum 123465:</span>
        <span>25 000 €</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="content">
        <span>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem lorem:</span>
        <span> 659 €</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```